# How can I fix? Systems says "Host is down" and will not boot

Tags: bash, debian, systemd, tty, hosts

After reboot, Debian GNOME desktop starts up automatically, in tty. 
When I try to start or stop services with `systemctl` this message appears.

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus. Host is down.
```

I cannot boot my system normally. With `startx` is appears on a server desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

RIP systemd.

Use *service* instead. type in

```
# service --status-all
```

and see if it is functional. Then do all of your above commands using service syntax and you should be functional.

Once you are running normally, take some time and dig into why systemd is not functioning properly.

Comment: I did all of this but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your symlink `/sbin/init` is broken. To check and fix that please check out this post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573609/400822