# Debian Buster terminal autologin

Tags: debian, systemd, chroot, autologin

I'm repacking a Debian Buster Live ISO. I first unpack the `filesystem.squashfs`, then `chroot` in the unsquashed system, make my changes.

I want my ISO to autologin (terminal). I've followed [this techniques](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401798/338177), but I failed because I get the error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

So I can't use `systemctl`, which throws this error.

The answers I've found here to bypass the error say to use `service` instead of `systemctl`, which doesn't apply in my case.

---

Is poosible to autologin using another technique?

Is possible to get `systemctl` functioning inside a `chroot`, so I can apply above technique?

---

Tentative answer:

I created the file `getty@tty.service` under `/lib/systemd/system` and made a sysmlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`. The contents of the file.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

This got me into autologin. I'll wait for insight before answer my own question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you configure autologin in Debian Jessie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297252/how-do-you-configure-autologin-in-debian-jessie)

Comment: @JdeBP The problem in my case is that I can't run `systemctl`, wich gives me the error I posted in the question.

Comment: How are you repacking the live OS?  It doesn't sound like you are using this, but the live-build package is for building custom live images.  It's easy enough to use and you don't have to unpack anything.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This may be or may be not related to your problem, but the problem I explain here will lead to the same error messages you have shown due to a missing symlink.

I am not an expert, but in Debian 10 (Buster) the default init system is `systemd` which means `/sbin/init` (`/usr/sbin/init`) will link to `systemd`.

Unfortunately there is a bug I noticed when running multiple KVM guests which causes that the symlink `/sbin/init` which links to `/lib/systemd/systemd` is removed. I don't know the reason for that, however, I suspect that `org.freedesktop.systemd1` (I absolutely don't know what that is) could be the reason.

**Correct Symlink**

The correct output would be:

```
root@vpstest:~# ls -la /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jan 29 19:07 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

**Missing Symlink**

If it shows that, there may be something wrong:

```
root@vps1:~# ls -la /sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 53016 Feb 14  2019 /sbin/init
```

**Fix**

To fix that, I just remove that file and rebuild the symbolic link:

```
rm /sbin/init && ln -s /lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init
```

When you're using virsh you need to destroy and then start the guest:

```
virsh destroy vps1 && virsh start vps1
```

Comment: My issue was directly related to copying a vm image without shutting down the host first and this resolves it

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)